# Unable to load Header data for xml through SSIS into SQL table

Tags: xml, ssis, header

I am trying to load the below xml file into table through SSIS. I am very new to SSIS. When i import the data into SSIS through XML source . All i see is detail data meaning i see >> "Consider", "ID", "LCD Number", "Recording", "Champion(Timestamp)","Value".

With this data i also need the "Response" data which has attributes "Naming" and "Mug".
I am unable to find a way to get this Response data. Any help appreciated.

Link of the xml image is below.

Thanks.

```
<RESPONSE Naming="MM" Mug="Begin">
    <Consider>
            <ID="190001">
                <LCD Number="DR77889">
                    <RECORDING>
                        <Champion TIMESTAMP="2020/11/09">
                            <VALUE>75048.0000</VALUE>
                        </Champion>
                    </RECORDING>
                </LCD>
            </ID>
    </Consider>
</RESPONSE>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add XML as a  text. Pictures are not helpful. Overall, if you need all data elements and all attributes together, you need to transform that input XML via XSLT. After that XML will become digestible for SSIS XML Source Adapter.

Comment: Please delete your "Answer", and instead update your question. You have no answer, you are looking for one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around(If anyone is reading).

I added a parent node to "Response" and created another xml file (can be put into variable i guess) and then used that file to extract the "RESPONSE" information.

In XML path in control flow Select "PutresultinOneNode" to True and generate an intermediate file. This will generate your xml file with parent node. You can use this file into your xml source in data flow to extract the information.